# Optimising query with large WHERE IN and Date clause

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, mysql-8.0, database-optimization

I have a query similar to:

```sql
SELECT
    ANY_VALUE(name) AS `name`,
    100 * SUM(score) / SUM(sum(score)) OVER (PARTITION BY date(scores.created_at)) AS `average_score`,
    ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(scores.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")) AS `shift_date`
FROM
    `scores`
    INNER JOIN `shifts` ON `shifts`.`id` = `scores`.`shift_id`
WHERE
    `shifts`.`table_c_id` in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10……)
    AND date(`scores`.`created_at`) >= '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY
    `name`,
    date(scores.created_at)
ORDER BY
    `shift_date` ASC;
```

The where in can be up to 2000 IDs which may not be sequential and the created_at where can be up to 14 months ago. Currently, at those levels, the execution time is 10-20 seconds.

I'm trying to optimise this. I've tried adding an index on `created_at` on the `scores` table but that had no effect. I also tried changing the date where clause to:

```
AND `scores`.`created_at` >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

Which again made no difference.

Having read up on the topic, some recommended creating a temporary table but I can't see how this would have any benefit. I'm also not sure how to do this in one (is it even possible?) query.

The indexes on `scores` table are: `shift_id`, `employee_id`, `name,created_at` (used for another query). As I said, a `created_at` index didn't help this one.

The shifts table has indexes on `table_c_id` and `created_at`

Some sites suggest using `WITH` and `CTEs`, but again, I'm not sure how this would work or if the performance would actually improve.

The schema for scores and shifts is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `scores`;
CREATE TABLE `scores` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shift_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sscore` double(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `scores_hash_index` (`hash`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `scores_shift_id_index` (`shift_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `scores_name_created_at_index` (`name`,`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3140922 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `shifts`;
CREATE TABLE `shifts` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table_c_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `shifts_table_c_id_index` (`table_c_id`),
  KEY `shifts_created_at_index` (`created_at`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=536392 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

### Update

Using a lookup table for names:

names table: int unsigned, id, primary; varchar, name

```sql
SELECT
    names.name AS `name`,
    100 * SUM(score) / SUM(sum(score)) OVER (PARTITION BY date(scores.created_at)) AS `average_score`,
    ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(scores.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")) AS `shift_date`
FROM
    `scores`
    INNER JOIN `shifts` ON `shifts`.`id` = `scores`.`shift_id`
    INNER JOIN `names` ON `names`.id = `scores`.`name_id`
WHERE
    `shifts`.`table_c_id` in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506)
    AND `scores`.`created_at` >= '2019-04-03'
GROUP BY
    `names`.`name`,
    date(scores.created_at)
ORDER BY
    `shift_date` ASC;
```

Has given no benefit. Also an index on `scores` table for `shift_id`, `name_id` and `created_at` hasn't helped.

Comment: `SUM(sum(score))` seems wrong

Comment: @zealous it’s correct

Comment: Would be better to write a subquery and use `BETWEEN` instead of `IN`.

Comment: The in IDs May not always be sequential. Wil update the post.

Comment: Show DDLs for both tables. Replace `ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(scores.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d"))` with `date(scores.created_at)`.

Comment: Are `name` and `brand_name` the same??

Comment: @RickJames yes, sorry!

Comment: @Akina Added the schemas

Comment: You use `GROUP BY scores.name, ...`. So this field is not unique. And in the same time it is varchar(255). Recommendation - normalize data.

Comment: Even when there are less than 10 names in existence? @Akina

Comment: Yes. And then test the index `scores (name_id, created_at, shift_id)`.

Comment: @Shiv . . . If you remove the window function, does that affect performance?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it becomes slower……

Comment: @Akina I've added those and updated the post with the query im using and new structure. No performance improvement though.

Comment: In fact, @Akina, it has helped. Time is now down to about 4-6 seconds which is better but that still seems high?

Comment: Are there other columns in `shifts`?  As it stands, it is an expensive case of turning one int into another.  Getting rid of the table yield be a significant performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Avoid windowing functions (many of them are slower than one would think.)

```
SELECT
    ANY_VALUE(brand_name),
    100 * SUM(score) / init.tot AS `average_score`,
    DATE(scores.created_at) AS `shift_date`
FROM
    `scores`
INNER JOIN `shifts` ON `shifts`.`id` = `scores`.`shift_id`
JOIN ( SELECT SUM(score) AS tot FROM shifts
        WHERE table_c_id IN (...)
          AND `created_at` >= '2020-01-01' ) AS init
WHERE
    `shifts`.`table_c_id` in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10……)
    AND `scores`.`created_at` >= '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY
    shift_date,
    `brand_name`
ORDER BY
    `shift_date` ASC;
```

Notes:

- several changes with the state syntax.
- I assumed that `name` and `brand_name`  were the same
- By flipping the `GROUP BY` order, it may avoid a second sort.
- I used a derived table to compute the grand total, thereby obviating the need for `OVER`.
- This composite, covering, index on `scores` may help:

  ```
  INDEX(created_at, shift_id)
  ```

Plan B:  Use a CTE to compute `SUM(score)`, then finish the query.

Comment: That is a lot quicker, but the result is incorrect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169223/mysql-8-calculating-average-by-partitioning-by-date is the question I made about the calculation - it seems to be a weird one!

Comment: The reason yours didn't work is that `init`.`tot` is the total of all, whilst the window function is only aggregating by date

Comment: @Shiv - Then the subquery needs a group by DATE.  Or something like that.  (I don't understand the intent of the original query, so I probably mangled it.)

Comment: Having to add the group by and then a where to check the date is correct on the outer query slowed it down dramatically